# Can anyone explain the syntax error in this trivial SlamData SELECT statement?

Tags: select, slamdata

I have the following select statement:

```
select * from '/MOUNT_NAME/DB_NAME/TABLE_NAME'
```

Where `MOUNT_NAME`, `DB_NAME`, `TABLE_NAME` are just what they say they are.

The above syntax works just fine in the generated SQL statement when first opening a notebook and exploring the data. However, when I type in the same thing in a SQL window created in that notebook I get the following error:

> operator '(' expected; '/MOUNT_NAME/DB_NAME/TABLE_NAME'

Any suggestions? Am I misusing the Notebook behavior for writing just simple syntax? Must be doing something wrong since this seems so straightforward. Any clarification out there?

Answer (score 2):

The correct query would be:

`` SELECT * FROM `/MOUNT_NAME/DB_NAME/TABLE_NAME` ``

Note the use of back-ticks (not single quotes) to escape identifiers, which changed recently when  SlamData was [updated to use the latest version of Quasar](http://slamdata.com/news-and-blog/2016/02/19/slamdata-2-5-released-a-bold-new-step-into-the-world-of-post-relational-analytics/). It looks like not all documentation on the SlamData website has been updated yet.

Comment: Thanks John. That fixed it.